# Python Pandas - Compare specific rows and combine

Tags: python, pandas, rows

I have following data sets:

```
Group   LowerTier    UpperTier   Value
  1         0           99         0    
  1         100         199        0
  1         200         299        10
  1         300         1000       20 
  2         0           249        0
  2         250         1000       5
(...)
```

What I would like get w/ Python and pandas is following:

```
Group   LowerTier    UpperTier   Value
  1         0           199         0    
  1         200         299        10
  1         300         1000       20 
  2         0           249        0
  2         250         1000       5
```

In words: I would like combine all rows within a group which have the same value in Value under the condition that I get the min of LowerTier and max of UpperTier for the double value (e.g. Group 1; value = 0).

How can I get these table?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try `groupby` with `aggregate`?

```
df.groupby(['Group','Value'],as_index=False).agg({'LowerTier':min,'UpperTier':max})
```

First create the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Group':[1,1,1,1,2,2],'LowerTier':[0,100,200,300,0,250],'UpperTier':[99,199,299,1000,249,1000],'Value':[0,0,10,20,0,5]})
```

Then apply `groupby` with `agg`:

```
df.groupby(['Group','Value'],as_index=False).agg({'LowerTier':min,'UpperTier':max})
```

output:

```
    Group   Value   UpperTier   LowerTier
0   1       0       199         0
1   1       10      299         200
2   1       20      1000        300
3   2       0       249         0
4   2       5       1000        250
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have worked w/ a pivot table but I couldn't get the correct data frame.

Comment: You're welcome, good luck with Pandas, it's very powerful, and worth learning it!